# Clojure: issues getting the symbol of a function in a looping context

Tags: clojure

Let's take that Clojure code:

```
  (defn ^{:test-1 "meta-test-1"} fn-key-1 
    [x]
    (eval nil))

  (defn ^{:test-2 "meta-test-2"} fn-key-2 
    [x]
    (eval nil))

  (def some-map {fn-key-1 "test-1"
    fn-key-2 "test-2"})
```

<strike>As you can see, the keys of my map are Symbols that refers to functions. I don't thing there is anything special there.</strike>

As you can see, when defining the map the keys of my map are Symbols that refers to functions. However, when they are read by the reader, then they get resolved to the function objects.

Now, what I want to do is to iterate over my `some-map` map to get the meta-data for each of the keys.

I was thinking doing this that way:

```
  (defn some-fn 
    [m]
    (doseq [[fn-key value] m]
      (println (meta fn-key))))
```

However, what is being printed here is `nil`. This is expected since the meta-data is defining the symbol, and not the function. So, there is no meta-data attached to the function and it is why `nil` is being returned/printed.

So this lead to a question: is it possible to get the symbol that refers to my function "fn-key" in that context?

In that doseq loop, it appears that fn-key is a function and not the symbol of that function. What I need is a way to get the symbol of that function such that I can use (meta (get-symbol fn-key)).

### Question Resolution

This question got resolved by defining the functions that way:

```
(def fn-key-1
  (with-meta (fn [x] (eval nil)) {:foo "bar"}))

(def fn-key-2
  (with-meta (fn [x] (eval nil)) {:foo "bar"}))
```

### Revision of the Resolution

I revised the solution above to make it cleaner. In fact, if you were to type `fn-key-1` in the REPL, you were to get an anonymous function reference such as `#< clojure.lang.AFunction$1@15ab1764>`. The problem with that is that it make things difficult to debug when you don't know what is being evaluated. To solve this issue, I changed the two function definitions to use this syntax, which resolve this issue:

```
(def fn-key-1 ^{:foo "bar"} (fn [x] (eval nil)))

(def fn-key-2 ^{:foo "bar"} (fn [x] (eval nil)))
```

Now, if we type `fn-key-1` then we will get something like `#<core$foo user.core$foo@66e37466>` instead. At least, we have the namespace & symbol signature of this function object.

Comment: "the keys of my map are Symbols that refers to functions" this is false, the symbols are resolved and the keys in the map are the function objects.

Comment: @noisesmith I just updated my question to reflect that distinction, please review and make sure it covers what you expressed here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(def some-map {#'fn-key-1 "test-1"
               #'fn-key-2 "test 2"})
```

`fn-key-1` is resolved by the reader to the function object (which has no metadata to query). `#'fn-key-1` resolves to the `var` itself, and holds the metadata.

Comment: I didn't thought about using the #' macro directly into the map's definition. However, is it possible to get the Symbol of reference a function object from that function object?

Comment: the thing is that I don't want to use the #' macro in front of the keys of these kind of maps every time I need to define something.

Comment: Function objects do not carry metadata unless you have put it there. The code you use puts metadata on the var, not the function.

Comment: it makes sense to use `#'` (or the `var` macro), because a var can get at its own data, plus the thing it refers to. The thing referred to is intentionally ignorant about anything that may be pointing to it.

Comment: I have no problem having the meta-data at the level of the symbol. But do you know if it is possible to get the list of symbols that refer to an object (in this case, a function object)?

Comment: it is not at the level of the symbol, it is at the var (which the reader derives from the symbol). And no, there is no way to go from a thing to the things binding to it.

Comment: I should say there is intentionally no simple way to do so. It could probably be done by walking the entire clojure environment or something equally rediculous.

Comment: great, thanks for the clarifications and confirming my fear. But you seems to suggest that it would be possible to define metadata at the level of the function. I can test that using `(meta (with-meta fn-key-1 {:foo "bar"}))` which works, but is it possible to define metadata on the function when defining it using `defn`?

Comment: defn is just def + fn (plus some metadata for things like line number and doc string etc.), and you can add meta to the function in that way `(def f (with-meta {...} (fn ...)))`

Comment: great working! Put there was a type I think, it should be `(def f (with-meta (fn ...) {...}))` (the map is the last parameter of `with-meta`)