# Clojure: Defining a Macro that Uses the Carret (^{}) Metadata Syntax

Tags: macros, clojure

I am trying to define a macro like this:

```
(defmacro foo-macro
  "[name] is the name of the function to define
   [meta-data] is the map that defines the meta-data of the function"
  [name meta-data]
  (let [vals (gensym "label-")]
    `(def ~name
       ^@~meta-data
       (fn [~vals] (eval nil)))))
```

However, I am getting this compilation error:

> Unhandled java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Metadata must be
>   Symbol,Keyword,String or Map

I think this is normal. However, I am not sure how I can make such a macro to work, or if it is even possible.

Note: **I do not want to use `with-meta`**. Read the revision of the resolution of this other question to understand why: [Clojure: issues getting the symbol of a function in a looping context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000510/clojure-issues-getting-the-symbol-of-a-function-in-a-looping-context).

The only reason why I would use `with-meta`, is if you have a way to make it return a non-AFunc identifier.

Comment: What is the macro for? Maybe there's another way to accomplish what you need, can you be more specific about the use case?

Comment: @DiegoBasch What I need is a macro that creates a function. Then I want to attach meta-data to that function object (and not its Var). However, if I use `with-meta` instead of `^{}` then I get `#< clojure.lang.AFunction$1@15ab1764>` as a reference for that object instead of something more human readable like `#<core$foo user.core$foo@66e37466>`. Even if the documentation says that there is no difference between these two methods, the difference appears to be that what is returned by `with-meta` is not the same as with the `^{}` macro (not the same object reference)

Comment: @DiegoBasch tell me if it is clear, otherwise I will try once more by updating the question itself.

Comment: You have to have one of the items in the error after ^ because ^ is a reader macro. You could do something like  ^{~meta-key ~meta-val}, or use a string and get {:tag "something"}. My question was more about why do you need to generate your functions with a macro, as there is nothing in that particular function that you'd need a macro for.

Comment: I am not sure `^{~meta-key ~meta-val}` would work since the `meta-data` parameter is a map itself (which is used to provide the meta-data to the function. What I need to do is to let people create a series of functions, but with a specific pattern. So I was using a macro to enforce that specific pattern to follow. My problem is that I let them define all the necessary meta-data using the map. However, I am thinking that I could use keyword parameters for the common and more static meta-data values, and then an optional meta-data parameter where they could add more if necessary.

Comment: @DiegoBasch only if they would use that optional meta-data parameter, the macro would use with-meta instead of using the reader macro. That would make sense I think :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you do want to use `with-meta`, you just want to use it within your macro rather than within the code you return.

The form that you get by reading `^{:foo :bar} (fn [])` is approximately the same as what you get by evaluating `` (with-meta `(fn [])) ``, so that's what you want to do in your macro: evaluate the `with-meta` call while generating code.

```
(defmacro foo-macro
  "[name] is the name of the function to define
   [meta-data] is the map that defines the meta-data of the function"
  [name meta-data]
  (let [vals (gensym "label-")]
    `(def ~name
       ~(with-meta `(fn [~vals] (eval nil))
          meta-data))))
```

Calling `(foo-macro fn-name {:foo "bar"})` should give you what you want: a function with `(meta fn-name)` returning `{:foo "bar"}` which, when printed, comes out something like `#<user$fn_name user$fn_name@35df85a1>`.